# Git bisect with hints on user and file tree

Tags: git

I am trying to run a git bisect and to make it faster I would like to:

- only consider a subset of commits touching files in a given folder (where I know the bug is)
- and only consider a subset of commits written by me (as I am the only one who worked on the feature with the bug)

Is there a way to do that automatically with git?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To skip commits:

```
git bisect skip <commit-id-1> <commit-id-2> <commit-id-3>
```

To look for specific paths:

```
git bisect start -- <path1> <path2>
```